# Integral transform and $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Tags: soft-question, gamma-function

Probably this is a trivial question, but I am unable to find an answer: is there a function $v(x)$ such that 
$$
\int_{0}^\infty x^n e^{v(x)} dx =\frac{1}{n!}
$$
for all positiv integer n?

Comment: Such a function cannot be continuous, or even locally bounded. Otherwise we have some interval $(a,b)$ with $a>1$ on which $v(x)>B$, so $$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{v(x)}>\int_a^b e^B>\frac{1}{n!}$$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Alex, thank you! Is it also obvious for integrals $\int_0^\infty x^n f(x) dx$?

Comment: @Sasha If we let $f$ take the value $0$ I suppose it could be done. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: It seems merely allowing $f(x)=0$ is not sufficient. Things get messy when you allow $f$ to take negative values, so I'll need to think about that case some more.

Comment: @Sasha: do you mean $f\ge0$ or any $f$? 

Comment: @Pietro: Any f. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a special case of the *Hamburger moment problem*: given a sequence of positive numbers $(\mu_n)_{n\geq 0}$  decides if there exists a  positive measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$

$$\mu_n=\int_{\bR} x^n \mu(|dx|),\;\;\forall n=0,1,2,\dotsc. $$

There exist many necessary  and sufficient  conditions for the existence of such a measure. The classical text  *The Laplace Transform* by D.V. Widder is a good place to look, especially Section 10-13 of Chapter III. [Here is a link to the book.](http://archive.org/details/laplacetransform031816mbp)

**Addendum 1.**  If you do not care about the positivity of the measure $\mu$ then we have the following result of  R.P. Boas. (See Section 14, Chapter III of Widder's book)

For any sequence of real numbers $(\mu_n)_{n\geq 0}$ there exists a signed measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ with the following properties

$$ \mu_n=\int_0^\infty x^n \mu(dx) ,\;\;\forall n=0,1,2,\dotsc, \tag{1} $$

and

$$\int_0^\infty|\mu|(dx)<\infty.\tag{2} $$

Recall that any signed measure $\mu$ is the difference of two positive measures $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ and the total variation  mesure is $|\mu|=\mu^++\mu^-$. On the semiaxis $[0,\infty)$ a signed measure $\mu$  has the from $\mu=d\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a function of   bounded variation on compact intervals.

**Addendum 2.**    Consider the Fourier transform  of the  measure $\mu$ in **Addendum 1**. We have $\newcommand{\ii}{\boldsymbol{i}}$

$$ \widehat{\mu}(\xi):=\int_{\bR} e^{-\ii\xi x} \mu(dx) =\sum_{n\geq 0}\mu_n\frac{(-\ii\xi)^n}{n!}.\tag{3} $$

There is an obvious problem   with the above  equality: the series in the right-hand side may not be convergent for all $\xi$ if the momenta  $\mu_n$ grow too fast.    In fact  if the momenta grow fast, there  exist at least  two measures $\mu$, $\mu'$ satisfying both (1) and (2) above. In  your case  the $\mu_n$   decay very fast and my guess is that $\mu$ is unique.  (The  series  in the right-hand side of (3)   converges for any $\xi$ so it defines  a continuous function  $f(\xi)$ which can be viewed as the Fourier transform of $\mu$ in the sense of distributions. Now  use the Fourier inversion formula to recover $\mu$.)

In any case, the space of solutions of (1) (2) is completely understood. A good place to look is Akhiezer  book *The Classical Moment problem* or  Chapter 16 in the  book *Unbounded selfadjoint operators on Hilbert space* by Konrad Schmudgen. The story is quite rich.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I need. Don't you know if there is a constructive way to restore such measure?

Comment: See Addendum 2.

Answer (score 8):

Such a function would have to satisfy:
$$\int(1-x)^2e^{v(x)}dx=-\frac12,$$
but the left hand side is clearly non-negative...

EDIT: Another contradiction for positive exponents is
$$\int x(1-x)^4e^{v(x)}dx = -\frac{19}{120}$$

Comment: @Gjergji, the OP didn't specify the value of the integral for $n=0$, just for positive integers $n$.

Comment: But it's fixable if you replace $(1-x)^2$ with $(x^{1/2}-2x^{3/2})^2$.

Comment: Or $(x-4x^2)^2$.

Comment: A very slight modification, using $(x^{n/2}-nx^{n/2+1})^2$, gives a somewhat surprising result:  The OP's equality cannot hold for any three consecutive values of $n$.  (To be precise, this only works for consecutive values greater than 1; my earlier comment rules out the case starting at 1.)

Answer (score 4):

No. For the integral to make sense, $v$ must be at least measurable. Let 
$$X_k=\{x\in [1,\infty): v(x)>-k\}$$
and note that $[1,\infty)=\cup_{k\in\mathbb N} X_k$ so some set $X_k$ has positive measure by countable subadditivity. Then
$$\int_0^\infty x^n e^{v(x)}dx\ge \int_{X_k} x^n e^{v(x)}dx\ge \int_{X_k} e^{-k}dx > \frac{1}{n!}$$
for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you are not wedded to the interval $(0,\+\infty)$.

If $C$ is the unit circle in the complex plane, oriented in the counter-clockwise direction as usual, then
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C z^n \frac{e^{1/z}}{z}\;dz = \frac{1}{n!}
$$
for $n=0,1,2,\dots$